# Problem with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

Could someone please tell what is wrong with these lines of code. I'm new to ndsolve. Mathematica 9 tells me my expression is incomplete, worse, I'm making syntax errors and I need more input Am I setting up the ODE in the wrong manner?.

```
E4b[t_, x0_, v0_, a1_, f1_, m1_, c1_, k0_, k1_, e1_] := 
 Evaluate [
  xx[t] / . 
    NDsolve[{m1 xx ''[t] + 
        c1 xx ' [t] + (k1 + (k0 - k1) Exp[-t e1]) xx[t] == 
       a1 Cos[f1 2 \[Pi] t], xx[0] == x0, xx'[0] == v0}, 
     xx, {t, 0, 250}]]
Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[E4b[t, x0, v0, a1, f1, m1, c1, k0, k1, e1], {t, 0, 250}, 
   Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0.0, 250}, {-20.0, 10.0}}, 
   ImageSize -> {800, 509.3}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed, Thickness[0.01]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 2.0/\[Pi], 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Time (months)", Bold, Blue], 
     Style["Amplitude", Bold, Blue]}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Large]], pltMale50thIn50th, 
  pltMNoon50th], {{x0, 0.0, 
   Style["Init Cond (x0)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, -10.0, 10.0, 0.1, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> 
   "Labeled"}, {{v0, 0.0, 
    Style["Init Cond (v0)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, -20.0, 20.0, 0.10, 
   ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"} {{a1, 1.0, 
    Style["Force Func (a1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.0, 20.0, 0.10, 
   ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{f1, 0.0, 
   Style["Force Func (f1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.0, 2.5, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{m1, 1.0, 
   Style["Mass (m1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.1, 5.0, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c1, 2.5, 
   Style["Dash Constant (c1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.0, 5.0, 0.10, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{k0, 2.0, 
   Style["Stiffness (k0)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.25, 5.0, 0.25, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{k1, 1.0, 
   Style["Stiffness (k1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.25, 5.0, 0.25, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{e1, 1.0, 
   Style["Stiffness (e1)", Blue, Bold, Medium]}, 0.0, 20.0, 0.25, 
  ControlType -> Slider, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  DefaultBaseStyle -> {Blue, Bold, Medium}, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
  Paneled -> True, ImageMargins -> 0
]
```

Comment: What happens when you separate out the `NDSolve` code and call it (substitute values for the parameters)? Does it work? Does the answer look reasonable? (Why include all the `Manipulate` code if it's not part of the problem?)

Comment: First change your NDsolve to NDSolve. Mathematica is fiercely case sensitive

Comment: Another error is that `/ .` is used where it should be `/.`. Moreover, remove the `Evaluate`. I am reluctant to parse this further. Please activate syntax highlighting and _read_ the error messages.

Comment: You are missing a comma after the control for `v0`.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
Manipulate[f = xx[t] /.
 NDSolve[{m1 xx''[t] + c1 xx'[t] + (k1 + (k0 - k1) Exp[-t e1])
   xx[t]==a1 Cos[f1 2 \[Pi] t], xx[0]==x0, xx'[0]==v0}, xx, {t, 0, 250}]; 
 Plot[f, {t, 0, 250}],
   {{x0, 0.0}, -10.0, 10.0, 0.1}, {{v0, 0.0}, -20.0, 20.0, 0.10},
   {{a1, 1.0}, 0.0, 20.0, 0.10}, {{f1, 0.0}, 0.0, 2.5, 0.10},
   {{m1, 1.0}, 0.1, 5.0, 0.10}, {{c1, 2.5}, 0.0, 5.0, 0.10},
   {{k0, 2.0}, 0.25, 5.0, 0.25}, {{k1, 1.0}, 0.25, 5.0, 0.25},
   {{e1, 1.0}, 0.0, 20.0, 0.25}]
```

Now you can put your decorations back one at a time and fix it when that breaks.

See if you can isolate the key bit that absolutely had to be changed to get your code to work. I suspect it is the placement of the NDSolve.

Comment: "Now you can put your decorations back ".. .:)